# How to draw this chart in base R?

Tags: r

My data has three variables: viscosity, pressure, and temp. All variables are continuous, except temp, which is a factor in this dataset. Temp levels are c(0, 25, 44,98). I want to draw a chart in base R where x = pressure and y = viscosity. But I want to fit a separate regression line for each level of temperature. How can this be done in base R? I know how to do this in ggplot2 using facet_wrap, but I am not allowed to use ggplot2. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This shoyld rather be a comment, but a cannot comment yet. I don't have the direct answer, and you don't provide basic data for a reprod. example, but here are some information that can help. In [this advanced R class](http://www.thibault.laurent.free.fr/cours/R_avance/chapitre_4_avance.html) by S. Déjean & T. Laurent, the authors provide examples of code comparisons between base R and ggplot2. It's in French, but in section 1.1.2.2, they go over facetting. What they say is: "Making the above type of graph with the base R functions becomes extremely complicated: first you have to split the window into 6, then use a `for` loop to call the plot() function in each sub-compartment, etc. Before the arrival of the ggplot2 package, the lattice package, which is part of the basic packages, also allows to make conditional plots in a few lines of code. (...) the reader can find examples of comparison between ggplot2 and lattice in [this document](https://www.londonr.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/presentations/LondonR_-_lattice_vs_ggplot2_-_Richard_Pugh_and_Andy_Nicholls_-_20130910.pdf)."
There, slides 15 and 16 provide examples for panelling and grouping.
This might help you find the solution with your data.